# вычисление ряда суммы числа слагаемых

Tags: javascript

Вот задание: для всех значений X, задаваемых параметрами из набора: начальное значение А, конечное значение В, шаг Dx, количество шагов N x, ограничение на число итераций N m ax, вычислить функцию F (x ) как сумму S бесконечного числа слагаемых, заканчивая суммирование для каждого значения х при достижении заданной точности EPS.

Сделал функцию, которая считает факториал, функцию, которая возводит число в степень и функцию, которая с установленным шагом и числом шагов перебирает. А вот дальше не могу сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```js
function sum() {
  let sum = 0;
  let i = -1;
  let result = 1;
  for (let i = -1; i < 12; i += 0.5) {
    result = result + i;
    console.log("i", i);
    console.log("result", result);
  }
  return result;
}

function factorial(n) {
  if (n != 1) {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

function finding(x, n) {
  let stepNx = 12;
  console.log("el", x ** n / factorial(x));
  if (n < stepNx*2) {
    return finding(x, n + 2);
  }
}

finding(2, 2);
sum();
```

[image: пример]

Answer (score 2):

```js
function func(x, eps) {
  var r = 1; // result
  var d = 1; // denominator multiplier
  var t = -x * x; // series term
  var counter = 0;
  while (Math.abs(t) > eps && counter < 1000) {
    r += t;
    t = -t * x * x / (++d);
    counter++;
  }
  if (counter >= 1000)
    console.log("no convergence at 1000 terms");
  return r;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  console.log(-1 + 0.5 * i, func(-1 + 0.5 * i, 0.00001));
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы объяснить, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Zerojle3 Что Вам непонятно?

Comment: что теперь с этой функцией делать?я так понимаю что функция sum не нужна

Comment: @Zerojle3 Хм, вызывать, передавая туда значение аргумента функции и точность.

Comment: некорректно работает :(

Comment: у меня есть величина шага 0,5 , количество шагов 12, и начальное значение -1.

Comment: @Zerojle3 "некорректно работает" - ??

Comment: Вот смотрите, если шаг = 0.5 , то следующие слагаемые должны увеличиваться на 0.5. Начинаю с -1.  Должны выглядеть это вот так: 1 - (-1)^2 / factorial(1) + (-0.5)^4/factorial(2) - 0^6/factorial(3)... и т.д

Comment: @Zerojle3 Вы неправильно поняли задание. Все члены ряда вычисляются для одного и того же значения `x`.